# How can I index a collection and allow each index's variable to have a custom setter?

Tags: c++, templates, operator-overloading

So I have an object called `Vertex` which contains some parameters (let's call them `sx`, `sy` and `i`).  `sx`, `sy` and `i` each have special setters: ie, `Vertex` looks something like

```
class Vertex {
    public:
        float sx() { return sx; };

        void setSx(float val) {
            val > 0 ? sx = val : sx = 0;
        };

        float sy() { return sy; };

        void setSy(float val) {
            val >= 0 ? sx = val * 0.5 : sx = -val;
        };

        float i() { return i; };

        void setI(float val) { i = val; };

    private:
        float sx, sy, i;
};
```

I would like to be able to iterate through a `Vertex`'s parameters without having to call each setter.  For example:

```
Vertex* v = new Vertex();
for (int i = 0; i < Vertex::size; i++)
    (*v)[i] = 0;
```

or something like that, instead of having to use the clunkier notation:

```
Vertex* v = new Vertex();
v->sx = 0;
v->sy = 0;
v->i = 0;
```

Is there any way to accomplish this in a more elegant way than just overloading `operator[]` and using a `switch` statement?  I don't need to use the exact notation I demonstrated above, I just need a way to iterate through the components of a `Vertex` without caring about the custom setters of each of them.

Comment: Why are you using new on the Vertex. For simple examples like that it is more adroit to just create the object (rather then dynamically creating the object).

Comment: I don't see a `Vertex::size` in your definitions.  However, if you want to address positions in array notation, why not keep them as an array?  Then `float i() { return mem[2]; }` or something like that.

Comment: If you only want to zero all components you could just use `memset`.

Answer (score 3):

Stealing from James Curran (and adapting slightly):

(James if you want to claim this method I will delete). :-)

```
class Vertex {
  public:
    float sx() const        {return data[0];}
    float sy() const        {return data[1];}
    float i()  const        {return data[2];}

    void setSx(float val)   {data[0] = val >  0 ? val       : 0;   }
    void setSy(float val)   {data[1] = val >= 0 ? val * 0.5 : -val;}
    void setI(float val)    {data[2] = val;                        }

    float& operator[](int n)
    {
           return data[n];
    }

    float const& operator[](int n) const
    {
           return data[n];
    }

    static std::size_t size() {return 3;}

  private:
    float data[3];
};
```

Comment: @Andreas: Where do you see that in the question?

Comment: Hmm... Now, why didn't I see that.....  (BTW, the least you coulda done is up-voted me....)

Comment: @James Curran: Copy and post this into your answer and I will delete this.

Answer (score 2):

You could create an array of pointers to floats, and index off that, but I'm  not sure if the result would qualify as "most elegant"

```
class Vertex { 
      float* varptr[3];
    public: 
        Vertex ()
        {
              varptr[0] = &(this.sx);
              varptr[1] = &(this.sy);
              varptr[2] = &(this.i);
         }
         float& operator[](int n)
         {
               return *varptr[n];
         }
```

Comment: Since sx, sy and i are only accessed through methods they just need to be in the array. There is no need to have an array of pointers to members aswell.

Comment: Notice that this will make it need a copy constructor and copy assignment operator to work (as opposed to @Martin's solution and the initial class by questioner).

Answer (score 2):

How about a reset method().
Or just do it in the constructor so when you create it the object is correctly initialized.